# How can I install aircrack-ng application in android using termux?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, aircrack-ng

I'm new to Kali and termux as well. I want to install aircrack-ng on my android so, how to install it by typing commands in termux.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Kali Linux is a niche Linux distro, which you may be using fully aware of what it is and why, for particular reasons- if so, please disregard this comment! If not, I would *strongly* recommend reading [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) over on Unix & Linux StackExchange. **It could save you a lot of time and hassle** :)

Comment: In addition, it's not clear to me from "I want to use aircrack-ng on my android" whether you want to install `aircrack-ng` on your Android phone (which would be off-topic here) or something else.

Comment: Lastly, please **edit your question** to show what you've tried and what research you've done before asking, to help people trying to answer you

Comment: i didnot try anything without being sure so I just posted here

Answer (score 2):

Termux is not a complete linux distro. You will need to find an appropriate source for aircrack-ng matching your devices architecture. As of now, it is not available in the termux repository.

Also, aircrack-ng requires the wifi card to be able to go in to promiscuous mode. Most devices don't support that.

You can check if your device supports kali nethunter.